# jQuery UI draggable issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm having issues with jQuery UI's draggable. Basically whenever I'm clicking the handle the box that's supposed to be draggable follows the mouse cursor without stopping.

The error Chrome is throwing me is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_mouseUp' of undefined

Does anyone have a clue what might be the issue here? Maybe other plugin conflicts ( I'm also using on the same page blueimp's uploader, fancybox and a particular colour picker )?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your code, plus give the details of the other plugins of frameworks you're using.

Comment: What versions of jQuery and jQuery UI are you loading?

Comment: We're not magicians. How could we possibly help you without seeing your code and knowing what version of jquery you are using ?

Comment: Wizards :)!  
The version of jquery is 1.7.1 and jquery ui is 1.8.17 ( I've downloaded the package with all its components ). Point is that all the other options of jQuery ui are working flawlessly aside from draggable, of course.

Comment: I wonder if it is jQuery UI throwing the error, or another one of your plugins which is stopping the event.  Can you try disabling/removing all the other plug ins and see what happens then when you try to drag the object.

Comment: I've isolated the issue. The colour picker was causing the problem. As soon as I disabled it, the dragabble functions works fine. PS: I've been using this particular colour picker -> http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-color-picker/